# making the div width stretch to fit its contents

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="fixmywidth" style="position:relative; height:30px;">
        <div style="z-index: 2000; margin-top: 5px; height: inherit; position: absolute;">
          <table style="height:inherit">
            <tr style="height:inherit">
              <td align="center" style="width: 31px; height: inherit;">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" style="width: 31px; height: inherit;">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" style="width: 31px; height: inherit;">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" style="width: 31px; height: inherit;">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" style="width: 31px; height: inherit;">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" style="width: 31px; height: inherit;">&nbsp;</td>
              ........300 tds later
              <td align="center" style="width: 31px; height: inherit;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

how do i make the div with the id "fixmywidth" width fit the width of the containing elemets?
i tried width=100%
and widht = auto
but they wouldn't work
thanks a trillion in advance,
Lina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "containing elements," do you mean the elements that contain `<div id="fixmywidth"></dIv>`, or the elements contained *within* `<div id="fixmywidth"></div>`?

If it's the latter, Fabian is right, and the issue lies here:

```
<div style="z-index: 2000; margin-top: 5px; height: inherit; position: absolute;">
```

`position: absolute;` takes the `<div>` out of the document flow, so it takes up no space. Therefore, its containing element (`<div id="fixmywidth"></div>`) doesn't encompass any elements in the document flow, and therefore has no dimensions.

You can fix that by removing `position: absolute;`, but that may not fall in line with your layout goals.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible because the div inside it is not actually inside it, because of the position relative/absolute.

Im not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish there but if you remove those 2 it will size properly.

Answer (score 1):

remove position absolute from the immediate child of fixmywidth

Answer (score 1):

if you remove `position:relative` from 'fixmywidth', it should work.